# Query in RedShift using DBVisualizer fails in a particular instalation

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbvisualizer

I am running the following query in dBVisualizer

```
select top 100 * from analytical.dwh_sales where _material = '000032';
```

And is working propertly

But when the same query is executed in another computer (an export from my dBVisualizer installation to another machine) we are having the following error:

```
[Code: 500310, SQL State: 42703]  [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column "loc_XXX " does not exist in dwh_sales;
```

I dont if you can notice is adding a space to loc_XXX(space) . Not sure if is why is working in a computer and not in another.

Comment: First thing that comes in mind - different driver versions are used. Can you provide table DDL statement?

Comment: I just modified the query to select top 100 * from analytical.dwh_sales where _material='000032'; (no spaces between =) and is working. Any idea why?

Comment: It still might be driver issue, or maybe there wasn't spaces, but some different characters which were displayed as spaces. is column loc_XXX even existing in this table?

Comment: Yes loc_XXX exists. I will check drivers